# gdata-objectivec Architecture armv7 error in video sharing on youtube from iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, static-libraries, gdata-api, armv7

i am using gdata-objectivec library for video sharing on Youtube from my app, i am using xcode 4.6 and iOS 6.0 to do this but the compiled static library "libGDataTouchStaticLib.a" does not support for the architecture armv7 and armv7s.

can anyone help me to compile the libGDataTouchStaticLib.a for armv7 architecture ?
i have also posted [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gdata-objectivec-client/aAssnkaIz2A) on google group.

i have also seen this [sample](https://github.com/stuffmc/YouTubeSample_iOS) code and it successfully uploaded the video from iPhone simulator but giving error on device.

i have also tried to install it on device using xcode 4.3 but not got any success.
i have also changed some flags in target>build like header search path, other C linker flag etc and also followed this [tutorial](http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/)

i have also downloaded gdata-objectivec library from svn server using terminal window but i dont know how to compile libGDataTouchStaticLib.a using the command from terminal of mac os for armv7 architecture (xcode 4.5 or 4.6).

if anyone used gdata-objectivec library for video uploading on Youtube from latest xcode or successfully compiled libGDataTouchStaticLib.a for latest xcode then please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add below three items in your other linker flags in project's build settings:
-ObjC,-lxml2,-all_load. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `arv7s` from the `valid architectures` under `build settings` and compile it would work for you.